# ApplySymbology does not recognize existing layer (ArcMap 10.6.1)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, arcgis-10.6, error-000628

I have a script that (1) loops through a each row in a feature class; (2) creates temporary_layer_1 with the selected feature; (3) zooms to the extent of temporary_layer_1; (4) creates temporary_layer_2 with a matching field in a different feature class; (5) applies the symbology from each of the permanent (looped) layers to the corresponding temporary layers; and (6) exports the resulting map view as a PDF.

I've had success with the code on my laptop, running ArcMap 10.6.1. When I run the same code on my desktop, also 10.6.1, it fails at "arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management," indicating that the input layer does not exist. What is puzzling is (1) that the input layer was already used successfully in the code in the previous lines, and (2) the layer types for input/output of ApplySymbologyFromLayer are identical, as one is the derivative of the other. After the processing fails, I try to run the failed line by dragging the input layer from the TOC into the Python window and it still fails. I've tried using the full file paths with no more success.

**Failed to execute (Apply Symbology From Layer). Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter in_symbology_layer.**

Code below:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env

gdb = r'C:\***\***.gdb'
env.workspace = gdb
env.overwriteOutput = True

fc_2020 = 'basin_out'
fc_2010 = 'basin_x'
temp_2020 = 'basin_2020'
temp_2010 = 'basin_2010'

output_path = r'C:\**\**'

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('Current')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, fc_2020, df)[0]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_2020, ['SHAPE@', 'Station']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        station = str(row[1])
 
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)  
        ext = lyr.getSelectedExtent()
        ext.XMin = ext.XMin - 100
        ext.YMin = ext.YMin - 100
        ext.XMax = ext.XMax + 100
        ext.YMax = ext.YMax + 100
        df.extent = ext
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView() 
        
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_2010, ['SHAPE@', 'Number']):
            EXPRESSION = '"Number" = ' + station
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_2010, temp_2010, EXPRESSION)
            
        
        # make feature with only current 2020 row
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_2020, temp_2020) # temporary layer with the selected basin
        
        ### change symbology for each temporary layer
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(temp_2020, fc_2020) <-- **Failure Point**
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(temp_2010, fc_2010)
        
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, os.path.join(output_path, station + '.pdf'), resolution = 600, image_quality = 'BEST', colorspace = 'RGB',
                                  compress_vectors = True, image_compression = 'ADAPTIVE')
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, temp_2020, df)[0])
arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, temp_2010, df)[0])
```

Comment: I'd use delete management temp2010 inside loop.